# SAS Time format precision: milliseconds

Tags: time, sas

I have a field in my SAS dataset that contains the number of seconds since midnight. For example:

```
34204.050479
```

I can convert this number in SAS using the `format time10.` which gives me the following:

```
9:30:04
```

I wish to have greater precision than simply hours,minutes, and seconds. Can I get the following in SAS:

```
9:30:04:ms
```

where `ms` stands for milliseconds?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471229/sas-informat-datetime-milliseconds

Comment: yes I saw that one before... but if don't want the date beside my  time?

Comment: What happens with time11 ...?

Comment: bingo! time12.3 works! thanks!!

Comment: Might want to move that to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dirk Nachbar, the answer is to format time as `time12.3`